# Remove space from row names in R

Tags: r, gsub

When I read in a .csv file that has spaces in the headers and row names (because of the program I am using to make models), `write.csv` will replace the spaces in my header with ".", but not the spaces in the row names, even when specifying `row.names=1`. An example of what `write.csv` gives me is shown below.

```
         SPEC...1   SPEC...2
SAMP   1    0         3
SAMP   2    0         0
SAMP   3    0.05      0
SAMP   4    0.05      32.5
```

In order to use TWINSPAN in `twinspanR`, which is only available on github, I need to be able to remove the space from the row names.

I am sure there is an easy way to do this, but I have not found it.

using this call in `gsub` completely removed my columns and headers:

`gsub("[[:space:]]","",data)` or `gsub("\\s+","",data)`.

So, what am I missing here? I have tried, in desperation, simply going into my whole list of models with `fix(alldata)` and using CTRL+H to replace all "SAMP   " with "SAMP.", but that makes the whole R program crash.

Comment: Did you try: `row.names(df) <- gsub(' ', '', row.names(df))`?

Comment: @ Gopala, that works well when I am using individual data frames, but how would I implement that using lapply or a similar function? That is, the data frames don't necessarily have dimensions in a list (or at leas that is what the warnings told me).

Comment: Perhaps you can post the minimal data, apply family code you tried and the error/warning message you got? That can help us help you.

Comment: Actually, I was able to implement your bit of code there into a function that I could just use as easily as any simple function with lapply. Thank you.

Comment: `skim=function(x){ dat=read.csv(x,header=T,row.names=1) row.names(dat) = gsub(' ', '', row.names(dat)) }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gsub` is the way to go. If you're using `lapply`, you just need to be careful about your return value. For example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:3)
rownames(df1) <- c("A  A", "B  B", "C  C")
df2 <- data.frame(b = 4:6)
rownames(df2) <- c("D  D", "E  E", "F  F")

dfl <- list(df1, df2)
```

This will not work:

```
lapply(dfl, function(df) rownames(df) <- gsub(" ", "", rownames(df)))
```

Because the output of `gsub` is returned, and `df`, while replaced in the function environment, disappears once that environment is left. To get around this, we return `df`:

```
lapply(dfl, function(df){rownames(df) <- gsub(" ", "", rownames(df)); df})
# [[1]]
#    a
# AA 1
# BB 2
# CC 3
# 
# [[2]]
#    b
# DD 4
# EE 5
# FF 6
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. Honestly I never would have thought writing a line like that. I was considering the idea of writing a function that would read each .csv file and then modify it before moving on to the next. Probably would have worked, but the initial construction would have been cumbersome. This is much better.